# PL/SQL Cursor declaration inside begin end block

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor, plsqldeveloper, declare

I'm working on a PL/SQL script in Oracle.
I need to declare a cursor that works on a DBA_HIST_* table ONLY if the Diagnostic Pack is lincensed.
I mean if:

```
select sum(detected_usages)
from DBA_FEATURE_USAGE_STATISTICS where name in ('ADDM','AWR Baseline','AWR Baseline Template','AWR Report','Automatic Workload Repository','Baseline Adaptive Thresholds','Baseline Static Computations','Diagnostic Pack','EM Performance Page');
```

is not > 0

I have to declare something like (simplified):

```
DECLARE
CURSOR main_metrics_cursor IS
with main_metrics as 
(
    select snap_id, end_time, round(average/100,2) cpu_per_s
    from(
            --Si recuperano le metriche necessarie filtrando su dbid e considerando solo gli snap_id recuperati precedentemente
            select snap_id, end_time, instance_number, metric_name, average, maxval
            from DBA_HIST_sysmetric_summary
            and metric_name in ('CPU Usage Per Sec')
        )
    group by snap_id, end_time
    order by snap_id, end_time
)
select * from main_metrics;
metric_row main_metrics_cursor%ROWTYPE;
```

The problem is that only with the declare (without the open cursor phase) Oracle knows that I used the dba_hist view.

I need that this declaration to be dependent on first query result (if the component is licensed) otherwise I need to execute another piace of code, but I can only use the if inside a begin/end block and the declaration has to be done before.

Any ideas?

I need that the DECLARE block is dependent of an if condition

Comment: Your query will only tell you if Diagnostic Pack has been used, not whether it is licensed. You can only know it is licensed by working with your procurement department and comparing purchased licenses with your actual usage in the field, something that cannot (practically) be scripted, especially if you are using VMs.

Comment: Yes sorry, you are right, I misspoke what I wanted to explain, in this case I have only to verify if has been already used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you don't want to declare a static cursor, you want to use dynamic SQL to open a cursor based on a dynamic SQL statement based on the result of your query

```
declare
  l_rc sys_refcursor;
  l_cnt integer;
begin
  select sum(detected_usages) 
    into l_cnt 
    from DBA_FEATURE_USAGE_STATISTICS 
  where name in ('ADDM','AWR Baseline','AWR Baseline Template',
                 'AWR Report','Automatic Workload Repository',
                 'Baseline Adaptive Thresholds',
                 'Baseline Static Computations',
                 'Diagnostic Pack',
                 'EM Performance Page');

  if( l_cnt > 0 )
  then 
    open l_rc for 'with main_metrics ...';
 
    <<do something with l_rc>>
  end if;
end;
```

Comment: Hi, the problem is not the part that query the DBA_FEATURE_USAGE_STATISTICS  table but the DBA_HIST_sysmetric_summary table. The second part needs to be subordinated to an if block.

Comment: @DBA_developer - Which is exactly what my code does.  Unless I am missing something...